# Python sort a list with external key

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list of entries based on the id of the entries.

I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
entries.sort(cmp=None, key=Entry.id, reverse=False)
```

The objects in the list are entries which have an id.

This is the error I get:

> TypeError: 'InstrumentedAttribute' object is not callable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`key` has to be a function that takes a list entry and returns a value used in comparison.

As alternative to `lambda`, use [`operator.attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
entries.sort(key=attrgetter('id'))
```

Comment: this is much faster than the lambda solution

Answer (score 3):

As the error told you, Key needs to be a function, or more accurately, a callable object.

```
entries.sort(cmp=None, key=(lambda x:x.id), reverse=False)
```

Comment: And you don't need the cmp= parameter. Not reverse either, of course, but it's OK to add the default for clarity. But in the case of `cmp=` no clarity is added.