# Sorting a Two Dimensional List in python using Insertion Sort

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I want to sort a list of namedtuples using insertion sort in python, and here is my code.

```
    def sortIt(tripods):
        for i in range(1, len(tripods)):
            tmp = tripods[i][3]
            k = i
            while k > 0 and tmp < tripods[k - 1][3]:
                tripods[k] = tripods[k - 1]
                k -= 1
            tripods[k] = tmp
```

Whenever it runs it gives me a TypeError: int object is not suscriptable.
Tripods is a list of namedTuples and the index 3 of the namedTuple is what I want the list to be ordered by.

Comment: What type of object does `tripods[k] = tmp` assign to `tripods[k]`? What will happen next time you examine `tripods[k]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python sort a list with external key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071988/python-sort-a-list-with-external-key)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortIt(tripods):
    for i in range(1, len(tripods)):
        tmp = tripods[i]
        k = i
        while k > 0 and tmp[3] < tripods[k - 1][3]:
            tripods[k] = tripods[k - 1]
            k -= 1
        tripods[k] = tmp
```

I have modified your code. You were assigning `tripods[i][3]` to tmp, which is a `int`. That's why the compiler warns you `int` is not suscriptable.